# ports in freebsd jail fetching but not updating

Tags: freebsd, jail

I've created a jail to host my webserver/blog, but when attempting to build any port, I consistently get the message  "portsnap: Directory is not writable: /usr/ports".

Attached is a screen capture of my console outputs attempting to portsnap fetch/extract/update
[image: console screen cap]

I'm not certain how to deal with this. installing from pkg works, but I want ports so that I can build my own binaries (also, to understand what the heck is going on and how to resolve it).

Comment: The easy answer is "Don't build ports in a Jail". Build the package on the base system, or using Poudriere. Then install the packages you built in the jail.

Comment: Interesting. How would you go about that? Wouldn't that also be possible by mounting ports inside the jail, permitting access to the build?

Comment: In the port's directory `make package` and the package will be dumped in `/usr/ports/packages/`. [Setting up and using Poudriere](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-poudriere.html) isn't very hard either, and makes rebuilding packages for updates easier.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea - don't build packages in jail.

You could use pkg , or pkgng

But, if you want, create this dir

```
mkdir /usr/ports
```

And if its needed you could change permissions

```
chmod ... /usr/ports
```